# Changing the backColor of DataGridView cells doesn't happen right away on Color.FromArgb

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors

I've been developing a program which makes use of a datagridview to read a database table and, in order to beautify the edit of cells in the fetched data, I'm using the following line of code:

```
dgvtable.Rows(r).Cells(c).Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 180, 86)
```

This line is called from a Sub, `dgvtable_CellValueChanged`, where `dgvtable` refers to the datagridview object I'm using for this. The relevant code to get this code to work is this:

```
Private Sub dgvtable_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvtable.CellValueChanged
        Dim r As Integer = e.RowIndex
        Dim c As Integer = e.ColumnIndex

        'Change the background color of the changed cell
        dgvtable.Rows(r).Cells(c).Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 180, 86)    

End Sub
```

So basically, when I change the value of a cell, the cell's background color should change to my favorite green shade, to indicate it has been modified. This however, doesn't happen right away (the cell remains white), and to see the change take place I have to double click on the affected cell, which then turns blue, and then click on the text to edit, and then the cell turns to that shade of green.

If I, however, write this instead:

```
dgvtable.Rows(r).Cells(c).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
```

The change happens right away! While I could simply choose to use the default green, I wish to use my preferred shade. Why is this not happening right away?

Comment: Why are you using an alpha value of 1?  Why are you using an alpha value at all?  I tried your code and saw the behaviour you mention.  I used `Color.FromArgb(0, 180, 86)` instead and it worked as you expect.

Comment: By the way, I removed irrelevant tags from your post.  Please use ONLY relevant tags.

Comment: There's the chance that the DGV has swallowed the exception that is raised when you assign a Color with an Alpha value to an object that doesn't support it. So, the instruction is skipped. The Color without Alpha byte is applied after.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I wasn’t aware you could declare a color without the alpha value. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You're not "declaring" a `Color`. Declaring is for variables, etc.  You are creating a `Color` value and the documentation for the `Color.FromArgb` method lists all the available overloads.  Always read the relevant documentation.  The documentation for that overload says "The alpha value is implicitly 255 (fully opaque)", which means that you would have to specify 255 if you were to use the overload you were.  By specifying 1 you were trying to create a `Color` that was almost completely transparent. Not very useful, even if it could work, which it can't.

Comment: Lol I guess I meant to say I wasn’t aware of the different implementation of the function, but I see how my quick word usage can sound confusing. And, coming from a JS background, I assumed alpha values for opacity would be handled in the same way as in there and CSS. As in, 1 being the most visible, and 0 being the least visible